# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined at VueComponent.sessionChecker

Tags: javascript, vue.js

### [I encounter this problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqQQN.png)

THIS IS THE ERROR:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined at VueComponent.sessionChecker

I can't find where this come from this is the only thing that showing on the error thank you for your help.

I don't know how to solve this problem. can someone help me?

---

```
import { logout } from './logout';


export const sessionChecker = {
mixins: [
  logout
],
methods: {
    sessionChecker ( error ) {
      let title = 'Something went wrong, Please log in again';
      let wrong = false;
      if( error.response.status == 400 ) {
        title = 'Bad Request, Please log in';
        wrong = true;
      }
      if( error.response.status == 401 ) {
        title = 'Unauthorized action, Please log in';
        wrong = true;
      }
      if( error.response.status == 403 ) {        
        title = 'Forbidden, Please log in';   
        wrong = true; 
        if( error.response.data.message == 'Your email address is not 
 verified.' ) {
          title = 'Your email address is not verified. Please verify 
 first before we proceed';  
          wrong = false;
        }
      }
      if( error.response.status == 404 ) {
        title = 'Page not found, Please log in';
        wrong = true;
      }
      if( error.response.status == 419 ) {
        title = 'Session Expired, Please log in again, sorry for the 
  inconvenience';
        wrong = true;
      }
      Toast.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: title
      });
      if( error.response.status != 422 ) {
        if( wrong ) {
          this.logout();
        } 
        else {
          if (this.$route.path !== '/email/resend') {
              this.$router.push({ path : '/email/resend' });
          }
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
```

I hope you can help me in this problem. thank you very much!

Comment: When `error.response` is undefined then you'll see this error. Please cross check what is passed to `error`.

Comment: @Ravikumar how can i do that? thank you for your response